# AEM Tag picker widget on a page

Tags: html, widget, aem, sightly, htl

I am working on a functionality where the user selects a Tag from a namespace and clicks a button.

Currently, we have a text box where user needs to enter the tag ID. But its not convenient for them to know the tagID.

Is there any way to create a `Tags Widget` (or a `Path Browser`) on a component HTML, similar to how it works in the dialog ?

I know Coral UI dependencies may be an issue, but just curious if we can achieve that. I've never done something like this.

Comment: Do you need this on the publisher and for the end user of your page or do you need this on the author?

Comment: @Jens, it will be used by the authors mostly, but it can have usage on the publish as well. Any ideas ?

Comment: are you looking for something like this: https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js ?

Answer (score 0):

I hadwritten a similar answer here

> [AEM Tools: Tag Picker using Coral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58638196/aem-tools-tag-picker-using-coral)

I had overlaid the

```
cq/gui/components/common/tagspicker
```

in the apps folder, and then edited the piece of code in the render.jsp to pick the tags from the desired path.

AttrBuilder attrs = htmlTag.getAttrs();
.
.
.
.
.

```
attrs.add("data-basepath", cfg.get("tagsPath", tagSpace));
```

where tagSpace refers to the custom tag location inside the **/etc/tags/customTagSpace**

You can pass it inside an OSGI configuration or anything configurable, where inside the **render.jsp** you can pick up using scriptlets or other methods and then display it.