# AEM Tools: Tag Picker using Coral

Tags: jsp, aem

I have gone through this: [AEM Tag picker widget on a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55345318/aem-tag-picker-widget-on-a-page)
But did not get any satisfactory answer.

I have a tool made under `apps/projectname/components/tools/toolname/content.jsp`

I understand that this needs to be made in coral UI.
Anyway, I need a method by which I can implement an AEM Tag Picker (or a Tag Field) in this page which is written in JSP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had overlaid the

```
cq/gui/components/common/tagspicker
```

in the apps folder, and then edited the piece of code in the **render.jsp** to pick the tags from the desired path.

```
AttrBuilder attrs = htmlTag.getAttrs();
.
.
.
.
.
attrs.add("data-basepath", cfg.get("tagsPath", tagSpace));
```

> where tagSpace refers to the custom tag location inside the **/etc/tags**